# tabular(x): How to get top-alignment, if a picture is put in?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularx

How can I get this

[image]

instead of this

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=a5]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
Laptop & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
Laptop & \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `valign` option from the `adjustbox` package:

```
\documentclass[paper=a5]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l X}
Laptop & \rule{2cm}{3cm} \\
Laptop & \includegraphics[width=2cm,valign=t]{example-image} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```